# sql query to contain or like with single word for jobs and user profile skill

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

`profile_table` and `jobs_table`

**profile_table**

```
---
pid | name | skill

1   | john | .net, ssrs, report

2   | kyle | java, struts

3   | milo | php, apache
```

**jobs_table**

```
---
jid | title             | required_skill

11  | java developer    | java, struts, j2ee, hibernate

12  | web developer     | php, mysql, linux, 

13  | .net developer    | .net, wpf

14  | .net lead         | .net, visual studio, C#
```

Now, how can i match john skill with jobs required_skill

I have tried taking john skill as whole string and search with `LIKE` in mysql, but that whole result is a string, so it just search respect to `skill` not every skill in `required_skill`

And i want to achieve contains any of the `skill` in `required_skill`.

I have tried using `explode` and seperate code and storing it in an array, but i want do in database only on the server side to reduce speed.

Comment: I would refactor the database model and have skills and required skills in multiple rows, rather than multiple values in one row

Comment: Once you refactor the database finding candidates with any of the skills is a straight forward join. To find candidates with all of the required skills google relational division.

Comment: Your two choices are using text search or storing the data in a proper relational format.  SQL in general does not have any functions that allow you to compare part of one string to part of another.

Comment: you should refactor database  model. otherwise you have to write complex procedure to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A neater way of doing this would be to normalise your database so that you're not storing more than one piece of information in the `required_skill` column.

Get rid of the `skill` and `required_skill` columns from your existing tables.

Add a `skill_table` (I'm using your naming convention; I'd just call it `Skill`):

```
sid | SkillName             

1   | java
2   | struts
3   | J2EE
4   | .net 
5   | hibernate
6   | SSRS
7   | php
8   | apache
9   | report
etc...
```

Then create two more 2-column tables - one joining `profiles` to `skill` and another to join `jobs` to the same `skill` table:

**profile_skill**

```
pid | sid             

1   | 4
1   | 6
1   | 9
2   | 1  
2   | 2
3   | 7  
3   | 8
```

**job_skill**

```
jid | sid             

11   | 1
11   | 2
11   | 3
11   | 5  
etc...
```

`

Now you can write a query to extract matches either way - joining `profiles` to `jobs` via `skills` or vice versa.

Comment: Thanks i will be using INNER JOINS